# What is this "PCDATA invalid Char value 11" error?

Tags: xml, nsxmlparser, evernote, pcdata

I have to use a XML file but I don't get all the items because of this error which is displayed in my navigator, before the content of the file. The exact error is :

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 4099 at column 10: PCDATA invalid Char value 11 Below is
>   a rendering of the page up to the first error.

What should I do ? Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Fix the XML. Char value 11 is not allowed in XML.

Comment: It's the 11th char of ASCII table ?

Comment: As near as makes no difference, yes.

Comment: More precisely, it's not allowed in XML 1.0. Under some circumstances it's allowed in XML 1.1 - provided it is escaped, which I think it isn't.

Comment: The same situation, please check this question's answers :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229572/php-generated-xml-shows-invalid-char-value-27-message

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help at all, but if this error is related to Evernote then you can try this.

You can find the 'raw' Evernote content here on OSX:

`/Users/{your_user_name}/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/{your_evernote_account_name}/content/`

In that folder there will  be lots of folders named p1, p2 etc.. Each folder is its own note, you can scan through the folders looking at the card.png image to see which note that folder corresponds to.

You can then edit the content.enml to try fix the issue. Some info on the enml format is here: http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php

Comment: Why does Evernote do this?  Isn't that a bug, that it allowed a character to be entered that it can't render or even parse beyond?  In my case all I did was type in some text.