# XML Parsing error with a special char

Tags: xml, notepad++, special-characters

I have this error in the xml when I try to parse it:

[image]

The char is this 'RS':

[image]

I'm trying to understand what this char is.

Comment: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+001E

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP generated XML shows invalid Char value 27 message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229572/php-generated-xml-shows-invalid-char-value-27-message)