# Xml - PCDATA invalid Char value 2

Tags: xml, elixir

"PCDATA invalid Char value 2" error in XML file I generate using chrome. I would like to fix it, however I don't understand what "Char value 2" is. Is there some sort of list of Char values in XMLs that are not supported, so I can view them and fix this issue.

I am using Saxy parser in Elixir.

I reviewed that thread: [PHP generated XML shows invalid Char value 27 message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229572/php-generated-xml-shows-invalid-char-value-27-message) but it didn't help me

Answer (score -1):

If you have any special character in XML file, that must be encapsulated with `<![CDATA[<special chracter]]>` atleast.

Comment: sorry, the code part couldn't print. Pls check once again if it helps

Comment: Please see the linked question; U+0002 isn't permitted in an XML 1.0 document, encoded or otherwise.